# How to check whether a svg circle inside the svg path

Tags: d3.js, svg

There are many ways to check is point inside path, but i haven't found any algorhitm which can check if the circle(whole object, not center point) is inside svg path.
If you're wondering why I need this algorithm - i want to fill space with circles with different radii (http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1893974), and those circles that enters the shape i want to paint in another color. As a result, we get the test image for color-blind people, like Ishihara's pictures.

[The expected result like on that picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1cM8.jpg)

Comment: Looka this sample: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4218871 .Even has same colors :)

Comment: I saw this example, but it's all about intersection, i need entrance

Comment: There are distance from path algorithms out there (search "nearest point on path").  All you need to do is check that the center of the circle is inside the path **and** that the distance to the path is greater than the radius.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau, thank you so much, this is exactly what i was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

This a collition detection algorithm or intersection.

**Step 1**

Fill with cirlcles you base shape

[image]

**Step 2**

Create the main shape

[image]

**Step 3**

Detect interserct and color the shape behind. And hide the main shape

[image] [image]

**Pros**: You can add dynamically shapes, animate or change it on the fly.

For an implementation look [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4218871)